# MySQL Workbench 6.1 CE não inicia mais

Tags: mysql

Não sei se alguém aqui utiliza, eu tentei utilizar pela primeira vez, baixei, instalei e usei a primeira vez numa boa, Achei super legal, criei um banco, tabelas, editei tudo funcionando perfeitamente.

Desliguei o PC e no dia seguinte não iniciava mais de jeito nenhum. Não dá erro, apenas não inicia. No gerenciador de tarefas chega a criar o serviço, mas some inexplicavelmente. Já reinstalei 2x e nada. Pesquisei em alguns fóruns e vi pessoas com o mesmo problema, mas nenhuma resolução, alguns sem resposta e outros disseram que pararam de usar.
Utilizo a versão 6.1 CE, é a mais recente, e Windows 7 Ultimate, 64 bits.

Alguém já teve esse problema? Conseguiu resolver? Alguma sugestão de programa similar a ele?

Comment: O serviço está ativo? vc pode ver em `iniciar>executar>services.msc`. Qual a mensagem de erro aparece?

Comment: Tente executar o `mysqld.exe` como administrador. Ele fica na paste de instalação do MySQL.

Comment: O serviço não está ativo. O processo é iniciado, mas logo em seguida é encerrado.
Verifiquei na pasta, mas não tem nenhum arquivo chamado mysqld.exe
E não aparece mensagem de erro. Só não abre o programa.

Comment: Eu utilizo, com a mesma configuração e nunca tive este problema, me parece coisa de antivírus, pois ao reiniciar deve ter bloqueado o processo, dá uma olhada no seu antivírus e ve se aparece algo bloqueado.

Comment: Mas eu nem usava antivírus cara. Tinha acabado de formatar o PC, só tinha instalado o ambiente pro PHP e MySQL. Nada além disso rs

Comment: Eu sei que esta pergunta foi feita a um bom tempo mas vou responder algo mesmo assim. Então, dá uma olhada no seu Microsoft Visual C++, pq o mysql precisa dele para algumas funções, se ele não estiver instalado ou estiver desatualizado o programa não vai nem iniciar.

Comment: No meu caso, estava faltando vcruntime140_1.dll. Basta baixar e colar na pasta do workbench!

Answer (score 5):

Tive um problema muito similar e consegui resolver da seguinte maneira:

1) Abra os serviços do windows:

[image: executar]

2) Localize o serviço do Mysql e vá até a aba de Logon

[image: Serviço Mysql]

3) Modifique o usuário colocando o usuário que você usa em seu Windows (este usuário deve ter senha e ser administrador).
Repare na imagem abaixo que no campo de usuário tive que colocar .\ e então meu usuário. Na dúvida vai em procurar.

[image: Seu usuário]

4) Tente iniciar o serviço.

[image: Iniciar serviço]

**Obs.: Abra o executar e digite: `control userpasswords2` e garanta que ali seu usuário está como administrador.**

Answer (score 3):

Cara, não sou programador nem nada, só estou respondendo porque tive esse mesmo problema no Win 10 64 bits. Pesquisei em diversos fóruns e não consegui resolver o meu problema.

Do nada o programa parou e não iniciava mais, desinstalei e instalei e nada.

Resolvi de maneira alternativa, fui no site MySQL e baixei a versão de 32 bits compactada (já instalado - é um pouquinho maior). http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/

Depois de descompactar, joguei a pasta do programa já instalado dentro da pasta "Arquivos de Programas (X86)", entrei na pasta e abri o arquivo e pronto.

Não sei se esse procedimento é correto, mas estou usando sem problemas. Espero que te ajude tambem :)

Answer (score -1):

Eu também acabei de passar por esse problema.

Primeiramente eu verifiquei se havia um workbanch instalado no pc e removi 0 mesmo que era da versão 8.02. Depois desativei o windows defender e o firewall, baixei o workbanch na versão 6.0 de 32 bits e instalei. Isso corrigiu o erro no meu pc.

Cheguei pensar em formatar o pc mas não chegou a tanto. no mais espero ter colaborado.

Answer (score -2):

Eu estava com o mesmo problema, as requisições devem estar desatualizadas ou não foram instaladas, veja:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-requirements.html

No meu caso o Visual C++ estava de 2015, instalei o 2015-19, reiniciei a máquina e voltou a abrir